# PHP Redirect and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a registration form.  The `register.php` is checking for errors such as `short password`
AJAX gives an alert with the echo error from PHP.

With PHP, after an if else statement
the user will be registered and redirected successfully to `Location:index.php` (good)

[`register.php`](https://pastebin.com/0Lq9X6P2)

**The problem is, if there is any error, the user will be redirected to `register.php`

and the echo alert shows there (on white page)**

---

AJAX

```js
var form = document.querySelector('.register form');
form.onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_data = new FormData(form);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', form.action, true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      document.querySelector('.msg').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    };
    if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 299) {
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      if (response.location) {
        window.location.href = response.location;
      } else {
        xhr.send(form_data);
      }
    }
```

---

Example 2: the alerts will display properly at `<div class="msg"></div>` position
(But will also throw the index.php on the msg div(same page where the alerts go)

```js
var form = document.querySelector('.register form');
form.onsubmit = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var form_data = new FormData(form);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', form.action, true);
  xhr.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector('.msg').innerHTML = this.responseText;
  };
  xhr.send(form_data);
};
```

So, i want the user to be redirected to `index.php` & also the echo errors `(register.php)` to be handled by AJAX

*Please understand that im new & learning, i spent a week in this.

If you choose to resolve this, please fix based off `register.php` and ajax code*

Comment: You can't do redirect from PHP if you're using AJAX. The AJAX call will read the redirected page as the response, it won't redirect the browser.

Comment: Sure, please check register.php and also the ajax code, based off this, let me know about my options ––––

If you choose to resolve this, please fix based off register.php and ajax code

Comment: Also im being redirected with ```xhr.status```  but also the errors (echo) are being redirected, & with the example 2,  alerts work as intended but no redirect

Comment: The `xhr.status` code needs to be in the `onload` callback function.

Comment: But `xhr.send(form_data)` should not be inside that `if` block.

Comment: It makes sense,  let me know how you would approach this problem

Comment: The PHP script should return JSON, not HTML. The JSON can contain a success flag and an error message. Then the AJAX callback function can check the success flag, and either display the error message or assign to `window.location` to redirect.

Comment: This will require a complete rewrite of the PHP code, more work than I'm willing to do for you.